# Unintuitive terminal connection to ground

Tags: kicad

I'm reading the [datasheet of an incremental encoder](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/PEC11R.pdf) and seem to miss something.

Am I reading it right that Terminal-C is connected to GND, and if so why?
I thought I'm supposed to connect Terminal-C to a GPIO-pin of my MCU; should I connect the pin to the GND net since Terminal-C is also connected?

[image]

My circuit looks like this:
[image]

Comment: `com` stands for `common` and is usually indicating a reference point, which is usually connected to the ground. So it is not clear to me why would you want to connect it to GPIO. It is also shorted to pin 3 on your schematic for some reason. What is that pin?

Comment: IIRC pin 3 is the the shield of the encoder.

Comment: And why would you ever want to connect the shield to GPIO ?? I also notice that all these together are shorted to the ground on your schematic.

Comment: My misunderstanding was indeed the need (or lack thereof) of connecting Term-C to a GPIO. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. The encoder has two outputs, A and B, which have pull-up resistors giving 5 V - logic '1' - on the output when the associated encoder contact is open. When closed the contacts pull the line to 0 V giving a logic '0'. The additional 10k resistors and 0.01 μF capacitors form a low-pass filter to remove any rapid switching due to contact bounce.*

[image]

*Figure 1. Encoder signals and resultant count.*

Most encoders are used to monitor movement or position so an up-down counter is required and this is driven by a quadrature encoder.

```
Pseudo code
// Triggered by encoder output A
interrupt {
  if(B) {
    encoder--    // Encoder is running anti-clockwise.
  } else {
    encoder++    // Encoder is running clockwise.
  }
}
```

You make the encoder variable as many bits long as required for the accuracy you need.

Answer (score 0):

The encoder can have any combination of the two switches closed/open, so it has 4 possible states. To carry this information using binary digital signals, you need two input pins, connected to terminals A and B, respectively. There will be 5Vp-p pulse trains on those as the encoder turns.

Now, you *may* use a single wire to carry the signals, and then a single MCU input pin, by switching from binary to a quaternary encoding, where a single signal can have 4 values vs. the binary 2. You'd then configure the input pin as an ADC, instead of just a binary digital input. See [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/460619/10810) for details.