# How to carry quadrature encoder data using a single signal?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, pins, encoder

A quadrature encoder can be thought of as two switches, usually sharing one of the terminals, i.e. we have COM(mon), A and B.

Is there some simple way of carrying its output on a single wire? How about interfacing that to a single pin on an MCU?

Comment: Maybe look up the 1wire protocol.

Comment: @Hearth Of course that would work, by using a 1-wire GPIO chip. It'd require a rather slow encoder input. Or perhaps there are 1-wire quadrature counter chips available? I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to convert the encoder's binary digital output to a quaternary (4-valued) digital signal. It uses only 4 resistors.

The only reasonable values for such a circuit that yield uniformly spaced output voltages require adding two unused values to the signal, so the encoding is really senary (6-valued), with two unused values (0/5 and 5/5), and the output voltages can be 1/5, 2/5, 3/5 and 4/5 of the supply voltage. For 5V supply, that yields simply 1V, 2V, 3V, 4V for various combinations of the two switches. For 3.3V, you get 0.66V, 1.32V, 1.98V and 2.64V. The "magical" resistor values are given on the schematic below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fviR3y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

These values of course can be scaled, i.e. all of them can be multiplied by a constant. For slow encoders like user input controls, one could multiply them by 10x, and add a 0.01uF capacitor from the output (marked "TO ADC") to ground to filter the signal. The truth table is as follows, with toADC voltage given relative to 5V full-scale (VCC).

```
  A       B  | toADC | 8-bit approx
------+------+-------+--------------
 open   open    2V        102  
closed  open    1V         51
 open  closed   4V        205
closed closed   3V        154
------+------+-------+--------------
```

Neither 0V nor full-scale supply voltage would be present at the output.

Then one could use the MCU's ADC to capture such signal. The ADC can have very low resolution - a dozen reliable levels would suffice. This low resolution requirement sometimes lets you overclock the MCU's ADC, perhaps by a large factor like 10x. The ADC's resolution will drop, but we don't need all of it anyway.

If the requirement isn't to save MCU pins, but only to save lines from the encoder, and there's no desire to use ADC inputs, then most MCUs could recover the signal using 3 digital input pins (ideally configured as Schmitt triggers), by using thermometer decoding, i.e. shifting the signal so that as its value progressively raises it'd cross the logic input thresholds of 3 input pins - this could be done perhaps with only resistors, or resistors and Schottky diodes, assuming that the signals change slowly.

Alternatively, if the MCU has comparators, then thermometer-to-binary decoding can be done using feedback: comparator B has the threshold set at 0.5VCC, and its output is scaled and added to the reference for comparator A, its threshold set at 0.3VCC + 0.4*B_comp_out.

Comment: Clever! +1.  Works with usual mechanical encoder circuit.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use an R-2R resistor ladder.

The advantage is that you need resistors of only one value.

Two 1R resistors in series make one 2R, or two 2R resistors in parallel make one 1R.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffQi03.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can use a dip resistor network to build the circuit. [image]

Comment: R-2R circuits work great when the encoder’s output is a voltage source of course. But cheap mechanical encoders are just switches: voltage sources that vanish. Your solution nicely complements mine.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a rotary encoder, let's call "switch 1" "Clock" and "switch 2" "Direction". We need to sample Direction every time Clock changes level.

It would be nice to be able to use a Pin Change Interrupt (PCI) for this.

This can be achieved by modifying the circuit in Kuba's answer to ensure that a transition on Clock results in a voltage level transition that is properly registered according to the the microcontroller pin CMOS input levels, thus triggering a PCI which would use the ADC to measure voltage. A transition on Direction would produce a smaller voltage change, measurable by the ADC but not enough to trigger PCI.

[image]

Here S1 is Clock and S2 is Direction. Resistor values can be adjusted, as long as a transition on Clock swings between V > Vih and V < Vil it will be registered as a digital level change and trigger the interrupt. A measurement with the ADC will then detect the Direction level.

The pin needs to be configured both as a digital and analog input, without pullup. Or the pin can be reconfigured on the fly between digital and analog input.

This methods does not require constantly running the ADC. The micro can even be put into Sleep mode, and woken by the Pin Change Interrupt. With higer value resistors, and a small filter cap, this would use very little power.

Please upvote Kuba's answer too!